# 14.04, unity not working after upgrade kernel to 3.13.0-27

Tags: unity, 14.04, intel-graphics

After installing new kernel update unity is not loading. Just blank screen without Unity panel.
I have tried to delete Unity and Compiz config files, and to reinstall Unity, but there is no result. I also tried to boot with older kernel, but there is the same situation with unity.
If in terminal (Ctrl+Alt+F1) try to run unity command, then will be message

```
 WARNING: no DISPLAY variable set, setting it to :0
```

I also checked if the video driver installed by runing lshw -c video, and the driver was mentioned there.
How to solve this problem? Maybe I need to reinstall video driver (but I don't know how to reinstall built-in driver for my Intel HD Graphics 4000), or maybe something wrong with xorg...

Comment: I think that could be related to this: http://askubuntu.com/questions/475683/unity-not-working-14-04

Answer (score 0):

Open the console by the following keys:

<kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd>

Then do the following:

*Use this to Remove/Uninstall Compiz Unity:*

```
sudo apt-get remove compizconfig-settings-manager
sudo apt-get remove compiz-fusion-plugins-extra
sudo apt-get remove compiz-plugins-extra
sudo apt-get purge compiz*
```

*Then to Re-install Compiz Unity use:*

```
sudo apt-get install unity-2d
sudo apt-get install ubuntu-desktop
sudo apt-get install ubuntu-desktop-2d
sudo apt-get install compizconfig-settings-manager
sudo apt-get install xserver-xgl
sudo apt-get install emerald
sudo apt-get install compiz-fusion-plugins-extra
sudo apt-get install git compiz-plugins-extra
sudo apt-get install compiz-plugins-extra
sudo apt-get install unity
```

Comment: Am I need to install unity 2D?

Comment: No, you can just choose what you want.

Comment: It seems that I have to remove ubuntu-desktop, unity, xserver-xlg before installing these packages?

Comment: I suggest you to do.

Comment: No result. Unity still not working. When I was runing sudo apt-get purge compiz*, near the end of output I got (gconftool-2:4185): GConf-WARNING **:Client failed to connect to the D-BUS daemon:
Unable to autolaunch a dbus-daemon without a $DISPLAY for X11

Comment: Try to install `sudo apt-get install ubuntu-desktop` and choose that one for now.

Comment: I installed, but I got the same  GConf-WARNING **:Client failed to connect to the D-BUS daemon: Unable to autolaunch a dbus-daemon without a $DISPLAY for X11. And Unity not working

Comment: Try to get an other theme, NOT untiy.